# Unable to get information about command ran in bash using Process class in C#

Tags: c#, linux, bash, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have ASP.NET core MVC application deployed in azure app service on linux. And when I try to run /bin/bash and execute some scripts like: dotnet run test.dll or javac Test.java and when I try to get some info about the exited process like MemotyUsed and TimeUsed I get the following error: "Unable to retrieve the specified information about the process or thread.  It may have exited or may be privileged"

When I run the app on windows everything is ok. I also try to run the app in docker on linux os because I think the problem comes from azure app service. However the same error was thrown again in docker container. So I think that problem comes from linux os.

```
ProcessExecutionResult processExecutionResult = new ProcessExecutionResult();

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    process.Start();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(input);
        await process.StandardInput.FlushAsync();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
    }

    bool exited = process.WaitForExit(ProcessMaxRunningTime);

    if (!exited)
    {
        process.Kill();
        processExecutionResult.Type = ProcessExecutionResultType.TimeLimit;
    }

    string output = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
    string errors = await process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

    processExecutionResult.ErrorOutput = errors;
    processExecutionResult.ReceivedOutput = output;
    processExecutionResult.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
    processExecutionResult.TimeWorked = process.ExitTime - process.StartTime;
    processExecutionResult.PrivilegedProcessorTime = process.PrivilegedProcessorTime;
    processExecutionResult.UserProcessorTime = process.UserProcessorTime;
}
```

When I try to access `process.ExitTime`, `process.StartTime` or some other information about the process the error: Unable to retrieve the specified information about the process or thread.  It may have exited or may be privileged is thrown.

Comment: You could try to install `RunProcessAsTask` library version `1.2.1` and later. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/jamesmanning/RunProcessAsTask/issues/15#issuecomment-355717029).

Comment: I had the same issue on centos, but once in a million. Still have no idea why.